# How to restrict an item on a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, restricted-access

I have a sharepoint list with numerous options, and I need to somehow make an option a list as confidential, being that on that specific item marked as confidential.

I need to make sure that itens marked as confidential are only seen by the admins on sharepoint and the one who made the request, but the items not marked as confidential should be seen by everybody.

The only "solution" I've found up to now is to make every item with a restricted view, but it doesn't really fulfill what I need.

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended for large lists, but you want to set item level permissions using a Flow.

The basic Flow would be:
On item created or changed
if field X = confidential
run steps to set item-level permissions

Google this:
Set list item-level permissions in SharePoint using Flow

Answer (score -1):

You can set Item Level Permissions based on Column and Field values by using SharePoint Designer Workflow.

You could refer to the following article to learn more infomation:

[How to Set SharePoint Item Level Permissions based on Column and Field Values](https://truapps.portalfront.com/how-toset-sharepoint-item-level-permissions-based-on-column-or-field-values.html)

Comment: he's using SharePoint Online and SPD 2010 workflows are dead and 2013 workflows are not far behind.